# Notice: Array to string conversion PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am loading a friends site to play with it and it gives me this: Notice: Array to string conversion  error. Any idea's how to fix this? (my friend is out of town)

```
function href($filename) {
    if (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on') {
        return HTTP_IMAGE . $filename;
    } else {
        return HTTPS_IMAGE . $filename;
    }   
}
```

the error points to the 3rd line on this code.

Comment: You must be passing an array instead of a string as `$filename`.

Comment: what is the `$filename` value?

Comment: What is `$filename`?  It's clearly not a string.  How are you calling `href()`?

Comment: A method you should know about... [`isset`](http://us1.php.net/isset).  It and `var_dump` will be very useful.  Suppressing, `@`,is rarely ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a string concatenation operator with something that is not a string. Namely, with an array.

Try this:

```
function href($filename) {
var_dump($HTTP_IMAGE);
var_dump($filename);
    if (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on') {
        return HTTP_IMAGE . $filename;
    } else {
        return HTTPS_IMAGE . $filename;
    }   
}
```

When you run this code it should display whatever is inside HTTPS_IMAGE and $filename.

As I do not know what they contain, I will explain with the following sample code:

```
$my_array[0] = 'Hello';
$my_array[1] = 'world';
$my_array[2] = '!';
var_dump( $my_array );
```

If you execute that code you will obtain the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "world"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "!"
}
```

That is an array. It is a collection of elements, which need to be accessed by index. For instance, to access "world" you need to access it by its index, "1":

```
echo $my_array[1];
```

Returning to your example, identify which variable is an array and access it by the appropriate index. You will know which index is by inspecting the result of var_dump().

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing array and string in a `return`. Try the following:

- specify an index to `$filename` (like `$filename[0]`)

or:

- convert it into a string with for example `implode()` function (like `implode(',', $filename);`, which gives you an string with the values of the array `$filename`, segregated by `,`).

Comment: How do you know what `$filename` contains? =P

Comment: @crush well I guess it's an array due to the error. I don't think more information is necessary to provide a solution in this case.

Comment: and there's always `var_dump` to prove what @DanielLisik mentioned